# MySQL Raw Data Backup and Restoration

Tags: mysql, database, backup

I am planning to migrate a large MySQL database from a Windows Machine to a Linux machine. The databases uses the InnoDB storage engine on the tables. Because mysqldump is so slow with large databases, i want to use raw data (files) to perform the task. I understand that when doing it this way, the hardware on both machines and the MySQL versions have to be identical, otherwise its complex to accomplish. Now my question is - Is there perhaps a tool that i can use to help accomplish this...maybe a tool that requires to pay or even free it does not matter? Please advise.

Comment: Not sure where you got your information about the hardware and the versions being identical.  I've upgraded (for example) 5.5.12 to 5.5.28 while moving the raw files from Solaris to Linux.  As long as the destination version isn't older or substantially newer, this is supposed to work.  I suspect "to Linux" is probably the least painful.

Comment: I actually read that in the MySQL documentation. The MySQL version on the Windows is old, and upgrading to the next version up would be missing out on so many new features and security updates. Are there tutorials or blogs that you would recommend because i could not find any addressing how to accomplish this in a step-by-step guide.